# Extra argument found by function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying following code:

```
class myclass: 
    def mymethod(a, L):    
        L.append(a)
        print "Sent number=%d" % a
        print "List=", L

mc = myclass()
Li = []
mc.mymethod(4, Li)
mc.mymethod(5, Li)
```

However, Python finds that 3 arguments are being sent:

```
$ python testpy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpy.py", line 10, in <module>
    mc.mymethod(4, Li)
TypeError: mymethod() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Where is the error and how can I solve this? Thanks.

EDIT:

On changing the code to:

```
class myclass: 
    def mymethod(test, a, L):  
        L.append(a)
        print "sent number=%d" % a
        print "list=", L
        print test
mc = myclass()
Li = []
mc.mymethod(4, Li)
mc.mymethod(5, Li)
```

I get:

```
sent number=4
list= [4]
<__main__.myclass instance at 0xb722a88c>
sent number=5
list= [4, 5]
<__main__.myclass instance at 0xb722a88c>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the `self` argument in your method definition.  If you don't know about that, read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial).  If you don't have any need for a self (as it appears you don't in this example), rethink whether you need a class at all.

Comment: Yes, it works with that. Is 'self' needed for every class method?

Comment: I will go thru this tutorial.

Comment: @rnso No, but it is HIGHLY recommended to do so because of convention when using class methods. It is used to access it own methods and attributes, but if it does not need to access that, feel free to leave it out.

Comment: @Uzzee: That is not correct.  It is true that you don't need to call the argument `self`, but (as this question shows) you can't just leave it out.

Comment: In your definition, the argument `a` is the instance itself. `mc.mymethod(4, Li)` implicitly passes the instance `mc` as the first argument `a`, and the number `4` is the second argument `L`. The argument `Li` does not have a corresponding parameter, causing the error.

Comment: @BrenBarn It still kinda is. Even though it does not need to be named ``self``, if it is used as a class method, it passes an extra argument as its first one. So what I really meant was, if creating a class method, the meta argument is needed, however, it is not Required to call it ``self``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the self argument in the class function. The correct code is:

```
class myclass:
    def mymethod(self, a, L):    
        L.append(a)
        print "Sent number=%d" % a
        print "List=", L

mc = myclass()
Li = []
mc.mymethod(4, Li)
mc.mymethod(5, Li)
```